# Can't call e.preventDefault on React element (div)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, browser

I'm building a fake text area that supports highlighting and cursor navigation. As part of this, I need to support keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd> keys. In order to do this, I want to prevent the default browser actions from happening (in Firefox on Windows <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd> navigates forward or back a page).

The issue is that the event object that is passed to my `onKeyDownHandler` function doesn't contain the `preventDefault` method. How can I get access to this method?

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import React from 'react';

class FakeTextArea extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onKeyDownHandler = this.onKeyDownHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onKeyDownHandler(e) {
    if (e.key === 'arrowleft' && e.altKey) {
      // e.preventDefault() doesn't exist
      console.log('no prevent default?');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        tabIndex="0"
        onKeyDown={this.onKeyDownHandler}
      >
      Here is some random text that I want to have in here
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FakeTextArea;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[UPDATE]** The event is just not visible, but it's there, you can find it with an old and great console.log(e.preventDefault)!

**[OLD ANSWER]** Use the event from `nativeEvent`:

```
onKeyDownHandler(e) {
    if (e.key === 'arrowleft' && e.altKey) {
      e.nativeEvent.preventDefault()
      console.log('no prevent default?');
    }
  }
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#overview

Comment: Even when I use `e.nativeEvent`, I don't see a `preventDefault` method on it.

Comment: Indeed it's not "visible", but it's there, check in this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/preventdefault-nativeevent-xoef1 =)

Comment: This is the true answer! I actually didn't even need the `nativeEvent` at all, I was able to just call `e.preventDefault` and it worked like a charm. I can't believe it was hiding the whole time! Thank you! Go ahead and update your answer to more clearly reflect this (and that nativeEvent is there to use but doesn't need to be used in this case) and I'll accept it. Otherwise, I'll update it for you later and then accept it.